# Numerical algorithm for generating nilpotent matrices

Tags: matrix, numerical-methods

I am looking for an algorithm to generate random nilpotent matrices.
(I have a similar questions about checking whether a matrix is nilpotent here: [Numerical algorithm to decide whether a matrix is nilpotent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76307724/8052809))

I already tried the following:

###### Rank 1 matrices

- Generate two random vectors v,w, with `v(0) = 1`, `w(0) = -v'*w`
- Seems to be quite stable, but it a only generates rank 1 matrices

###### Sparse matrices

- Generate a random matrix, and set values iteratively to zero until the computed spectral radius is 0
- Very slow, and leads to *very* sparse matrices.

###### Jordan blocks with base change

- Generate Jordan blocks with all eigenvalues 0, and apply some base change
- Numerically very unstable

###### Acyclic graph

- Generate a random adjacency matrix of an acylic, weighted graph, and then permute the rows/columns
- Fast, but the distribution of the generated matrices is not nice.