# Numerical algorithm to decide whether a matrix is nilpotent

Tags: python, r, math, matrix, numerical-methods

I am looking for a numerical stable algorithm which decides whether a matrix is nilpotent
(A matrix `A` is nilpotent if `A^dim` is the zero matrix)

(I have a similar question about generating nilpotent matrices here: [Numerical algorithm for generating nilpotent matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76307680/8052809))

So far I tried to compute the eigenvalues, but this seems to be very unstable, since the accuracy of computing eigenvalues depends on the condition number of the matrix of the eigenvalues of the input matrix.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use the definition to check if a matrix is nilpotent?

Comment: Wonder if you might get some answers in [scicomp.SE] instead

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding It seems to me that for non-integer matrices this does not work too. But, this could also be due to the fact, that I am not able to generate nilpotent floating matrices .

Comment: Nilpotency itself is not stable wrt perturbations. So your eigenvalue computation being unstable (IMO) is a symptom, not a problem in and of itself.

Comment: If your entries are rational, I might try rational arithmetic rather than floating point.